# Calling Graphics function from another functionJava

Tags: java, swing, function, graphics

I am trying to get a button to call a graphics function in java that will take the lives left and draw the appropriate parts for a hang man game. Everything is working except for the drawing. I believe this is because of the way I am calling the function but I'm not sure. Thanks

Code Button:

```
if(TempText == Label.getText()){
           lives--;
           panel2.paintComponent();
           if (lives == 0){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You Lose");
               buttonA.setEnabled(false);
               buttonB.setEnabled(false);
               buttonC.setEnabled(false);
               buttonD.setEnabled(false);
               buttonE.setEnabled(false);
               buttonF.setEnabled(false);
               buttonG.setEnabled(false);
               buttonH.setEnabled(false);
               buttonI.setEnabled(false);
               buttonJ.setEnabled(false);
               buttonK.setEnabled(false);
               buttonL.setEnabled(false);
               buttonM.setEnabled(false);
               buttonN.setEnabled(false);
               buttonO.setEnabled(false);
               buttonP.setEnabled(false);
               buttonQ.setEnabled(false);
               buttonR.setEnabled(false);
               buttonS.setEnabled(false);
               buttonT.setEnabled(false);
               buttonU.setEnabled(false);
               buttonV.setEnabled(false);
               buttonW.setEnabled(false);
               buttonX.setEnabled(false);
               buttonY.setEnabled(false);
               buttonZ.setEnabled(false);
            }
       }
```

Code Drawing

```
class ColorPanel extends JPanel {
final HangMan man = new HangMan();
Graphics g;
public void paintComponent(){
   super.paintComponent(g);
   this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
   if(man.lives == 5){
       g.drawOval(175, 100, 50, 50);
    }
   if(man.lives == 4){
       g.drawLine(200, 200, 200, 150);
   }
   if(man.lives == 3){
       g.drawLine(200, 200, 250, 250);
   }
   if(man.lives == 2){
       g.drawLine(200, 200, 150, 250);
   }
   if(man.lives == 1){
       g.drawLine(150, 150, 200, 175);
   }
   if(man.lives == 0){
       g.drawLine(250, 150, 200, 175);
   }
   g.drawLine(100, 300, 100, 50);
   g.drawLine(200, 50, 100, 50);
   g.drawLine(200, 100, 200, 50);
   g.drawOval(50, 300, 100, 50);
}
}
```

Errors

at ColorPanel.paintComponent(HangMan.java:2573)

at HangMan$3.actionPerformed(HangMan.java:445)

Comment: Side note on your code: instead of having 26 members for 26 buttons ... you could use an array of buttons; or a HashMap (where the key would be a string representing the actual character, like "a"; and the map value the corresponding button object). Having 26 distinct button objects; and handling them  like you show it in your code ... is basically very bad practice. Using array/hashmap enables you to **save** many lines of code.

Comment: @EddyG's suggestion is a great one. Not only will it save a lot of code, it will make the code **much** easier to understand and thus to debug.

Answer (score 1):

You should almost never call paintComponent or super.paintComponent directly, and you should not be using what appears to be a null Graphics object. I'm frankly surprised that you're not getting a `NullPointerException` with that code. And in fact, maybe you are -- you never show us enough of your exception's stacktrace for us to know what type of error you are getting (suggestion -- show the **entire** exception stacktrace).

Instead have your button press change the state of your drawnig JPanek, change one of its key fields, and then call `repaint()` on the drawing JPanel. Inside of the drawing JPanel's `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, call the super method, and then use the field states to decide what to draw.

For instance, your field could be something as simple as an int that gets incremented or decremented every time a wrong letter is picked, and then paintComponent uses that int to decide which and how many body parts to draw.

Check out the tutorial, [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to see the details of how you will want to draw in your GUI.

I want to second EddyG's recommendation -- use an array of JButton or a `HashMap<Character, JButton>` to help organize your GUI code better. This way you could create your JButtons in a simple for loop, looping from `int (char c =`A`; c <= 'Z'; c++) {...}`. This will make your code much more compact, much easier to understand and thus much easier to debug.

---

For example,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LetterSelectionGrid extends JPanel {
   public static final String SELECTED_LETTER = "selected letter";
   private Map<Character, AbstractButton> buttonMap = new HashMap<>();

   public LetterSelectionGrid() {
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Select Letters"));
      ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
      setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0));
      for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
         String text = String.valueOf(c);
         JButton button = new JButton(text);
         button.addActionListener(buttonListener);
         add(button); // add to GUI
         buttonMap.put(c, button);
      }
   }

   private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         AbstractButton btn = (AbstractButton) e.getSource();
         char selectedChar = e.getActionCommand().charAt(0); 

         btn.setEnabled(false);
         firePropertyChange(SELECTED_LETTER, null, selectedChar);
      }
   }

   public void setAllEnabled(boolean enabled) {
      for (AbstractButton btn : buttonMap.values()) {
         btn.setEnabled(enabled);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      final LetterSelectionGrid letterSelectionGrid = new LetterSelectionGrid();

      JButton resetButton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Reset") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            letterSelectionGrid.setAllEnabled(true);
         }
      });
      JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
      southPanel.add(resetButton);

      letterSelectionGrid.addPropertyChangeListener(LetterSelectionGrid.SELECTED_LETTER, new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("Selected Letter is: " + evt.getNewValue());
         }
      });

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ButtonGrid");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(letterSelectionGrid);
      frame.getContentPane().add(southPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```